# submit only check values from form w/ pre populated data - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form w/ checkboxes, and would like to submit only the checked values.  The idea is to pre-populate the form fields with data from an API.  The fields will be disabled by default when it loads, and they can be enabled to edit/submit by checking any boxes.  Each field has its own `ng-model`, which is an object, and I want to see only the checked values on submit.

here is a screenshot of the form, right now I don't see the pre-populated data.  I set the `value` property from the `$scope.preData`, but I think it's being overwritten by the `ng-model="jsonForm"`.

[image]

Here is the api object for the pre data

```
{
  header: 'header predata',
  delimiter: 'delimiter predata',
  filename: 'filename predata'
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
$http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: 'api/templates/1',
                  headers: {
                      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenService.getToken()
                  }

                }).then(function(response) {

                  $scope.preData = response.data;

                });

$scope.submitJSON = function(form){
            console.log(form);
          }
```

html form

```
<form ng-submit="submitJSON(jsonForm)">
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="headerInput" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Header</label>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <input class="form-control" value="preData.header" type="text" id="headerInput" ng-disabled="headerRedirect==false" ng-model="jsonForm.params.header">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="headerRedirect"> Enable
  </label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="delimiterInput" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Delimiter</label>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="delimiterInput"
  value="{{preData.delimiter}}"
  ng-disabled="delimiterRedirect==false" ng-model="jsonForm.params.delimiter">
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
  <label class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="delimiterRedirect"> Enable
  </label>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
 <label for="filenameInput" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Filename</label>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="filenameInput" ng-disabled="filenameRedirect==false" ng-model="jsonForm.params.filename" value="{{preData.filename}}">
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox">
  <label class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filenameRedirect"> Enable
  </label>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
 <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

I tried to do `ng-true-value` but that didn't work.  I also set the `response.data` equal to `$scope.jsonForm`, which it populated but when I submit with checked fields, it submitted all the fields and not the checked ones.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Right now when I enable a field and enter a value, I'm able to see the checked value.  It would be awesome if I can see the pre data on load and checked any of them if want to submit the selected ones.

For example if I checked only header, my expected output will be:

```
{
  params: {
    header: 'my value'
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is `jsonForm.params`?

Comment: @dfsq `jsonForm.params` is the new object I want to send.  So the output will be `{ params: { header: '', delimiter: '', filename: ''}}`.  Of course the contents of params will be based on the checked values.

Comment: You don't need it, use `preData` to bind and construct new object when you make request.

Comment: @dfsq I'm sorry, I'm not following what you are suggesting.  can you provide an example?